# Разрешить SWF-ролику загружать локальные файлы

Tags: flash, загрузка

При запуске на декстопе, swf иногда не читает файлы (к примеру, xml), которые загружаются по ходу ее исполнения. Причем, файл, создающийся Flash Develop-ом, читает свою xml прекрасно, но, стоит его скопировать куда-нибудь, он перестает ее читать.
Я так понимаю, дело в правах доступа или чем-то подобном.

Как можно, при локальном запуске флешки (AIR не подойдет, т.к. нет возможности установит приложение), читать указанные локальные файлы?

Скорее всего это можно сделать одним из 2х способов:

- Дать права файлу (как?)
- Через класс System (использую AS 3.0)

Но как конкретно, я не нашла. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае (если это точно не AIR приложение), то никак.

То что вы запускаете в IDE, работает в эмулируемом вебсервере, поэтому читает файл, как клиент с сервера. При запуске "снаружи" ничего ей не будет доступно. Это логичная политика безопасности.

Сама по себе флешка даже не знает что такое файловая система клиентского устройства. Там закрыта компиляция соответствующих классов, и сам флеш плеер не имеет такой возможности в принципе.

Есть вариант сделать из флешки Project-EXE файл. Такая возможность есть в Stand Alone плеере. Тогда полученный EXE файл будет при запуске загружать локальные файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Надо разрешить запускать файлы. Т.е. создать доверенную папку. Если флеш плеер выше 10 версии, то зайти в "Мой Компьютер", там в "Панель Управления" и поклацать настройки. Будет "доверенная папка".